# How to update an array, by inserting an element at the first position

Tags: mongodb, scala

I want to update a document by adding a new element at the first position, in an array.

What I'm actually doing :

```
val updateRequest = myCollection.findOneAndUpdate(and(equal("site_id", new ObjectId(siteId)),and(equal("image_name", imageName))),
    addToSet("url_history", urlHistory))
```

**The result :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e297ea0c7ede90a7ae7586e"),
    "image_name" : "test.jpg",
    "url_history" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-02-08T10:43:47.127Z"),
            "url" : "No image url"
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-02-11T10:43:47.127Z"),
            "url" : "test.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The desired result :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e297ea0c7ede90a7ae7586e"),
    "image_name" : "test.jpg",
    "url_history" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-02-11T10:43:47.127Z"),
            "url" : "test.jpg"  
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-02-08T10:43:47.127Z"),
            "url" : "No image url"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution !

Here it is :

```
  val updateRequest = myCollection.findOneAndUpdate(and(equal("site_id", new ObjectId(siteId)),and(equal("image_name", imageName))),
  pushEach("url_history", PushOptions().position(0), urlHistory))
```

I used the **PushOptions**.

Hope it helps.

Source :
 https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.6/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/model/Updates$.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the "$position" operator? Take a look https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/

Using mongoose would be like this:

```
const schema = Schema({ nums: [Number] });
const Model = mongoose.model('Test', schema);

const doc = await Model.create({ nums: [3, 4] });
doc.nums.push(5); // Add 5 to the end of the array
await doc.save();

// You can also pass an object with `$each` as the
// first parameter to use MongoDB's `$position`
doc.nums.push({
  $each: [1, 2],
  $position: 0
});
doc.nums; // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

from mongoose docs

And do you really need to insert it in the first position? Maybe is a good idea to preserve the array order and when you fetch its values you can just order by the way you desire, what do you think about it?

Comment: I found the  "$position" operator and i already used it in mongo shell, but i don"t know how to use it in scala .

Thank for you advice, but for some great reasons, I have to put it at the first position (among others, to not have to go through the whole array)